# java security classloader

Tags: java, security, classloader

I am implementing a service which uses a `URLClassloader` to load classes dynamically.

In the interest of security I would like to restrict the access of loaded classes. eg no network, file or db access etc.

Anybody got any good resources or tutorials on the web for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Google for "JavaSeal". But they didn't publish the code though.

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/classloaders/ might be useful